# Selecting non-SMR external drives

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I recently bought a batch of 6 "WD elements" external HDDs and quickly found out that - for three of them - the write performance was precipitously degradating. Circumstantial evidence points to shingled (SMR) technology: format followed by trim restores acceptable writing speed, again degradating when used space goes above 50%.

These disks (used for backup) need replacing, and I am of course going to avoid SMR like the plague, but how? Transparency in labeling does not appear to be WD's forte, and I am wondering how to tell SMRs apart from non-SMR, i.e. brands and telltale labels I should look for.

Ideas?
TIA

Comment: Better ask your question here: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try r/datahoarder for that.

Comment: Check here!!! Best site! https://rml527.blogspot.com/2010/09/hdd-platter-database-western-digital.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to verify with the manufacturer, but usually CMR is used for
disks destined to sustain good random writes.

The MiniTool Tips article
[CMR vs SMR: What Are the Differences & Which One Is Better](https://www.minitool.com/backup-tips/cmr-vs-smr.html)
from 2022 has this summary :

> **Seagate**: New Barracuda from 1TB to 8TB is usually SMR, while Ironwolf is usually a CMR hard drive.
>
> **Toshiba**: Many of their 1TB to 6TB drives are usually SMR. Other products like X300, P300, and N300 are usually CMR.
>
> **Western Digital**: Its variety is very diverse. The red series is a mix of SMRs and CMRs. Red Pro is CMR, blue is mixed, black is mostly
> CMR, and purple is CMR.

Your best guide is probably searching for a benchmark for the disk you
intend to buy. If writing speed is low, and especially random write,
then the disk uses SMR. The disk slowing down as it fills up is
another danger-sign.